# Users cannot change the contact email address for Notifications in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

A number of users went into DevOps, clicked their avatar and chose My Profile => Edit Profile. The email defaulted to myname@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com. They edited this to myname@mycompany.com and confirmed via the email. This worked great for one user - they receive all the correct notifications. When that user looks at his notification settings (Avatar => Notification Settings) the correct @mycompany.com email address is shown. For other users, the contact email address is changed but the notification settings page still shows the onmicrosoft email address. They do not receive notifications.

They have tried subscribing manually for the notifications and it worked but @mentions still do not work.

Comment: change it to something temporary and change it back to a real thing?

Comment: @4c74356b41 We tried changing and changing back with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this @Justin?